# tar: could not chdir to 'dirname' when using -C with tar

Tags: command-line, tar

I downloaded [this file](https://github.com/psf/requests/tarball/main) and when I try to use `-C` with `tar` to change the name of the directory it outputs to, I get this error

```
$ tar -xvf requests.tar -C requests
tar: could not chdir to 'requests'
```

I don't get this error when extracting files without `-C`. I tried this in `/tmp` and `~/Desktop` I also tried passing an absolute path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

man tar tells you the issue

> -C directory, --cd directory, --directory directory
> In c and r mode, this changes the directory before adding the following files.  In x mode, change directories after opening the archive but before extracting entries
> from the archive.

Thus you have to have the directory created before you change into it.

Without the -C tar extracts to the current directory

Thus for file dir/a.txt in the tarred file

With -C requests the file ends up in requests/dir/a.txt

whilst with no argument it ends up in ./dir/a.txt